# Rails only responds to 'page:change' on localhost. only 'turbolinks:load' in production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, turbolinks

When I run my app on localhost jquery loads my function on 'page:change', but not on 'turbolinks:load'. In production on Heroku it's the other way round: my function loads on 'turbolinks:load', but not 'page:change'.

Both systems are running Rails 4.2.5.1
Both systems are running ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

Why do I need to use different commands in different places?

Comment: What version of Turbolinks do you have in your gemfile?  Turbolinks 5 is the standard on Rails5 and that uses turbolinks:load but you may have TLinks 4 on your Rails4 app.

Comment: Thanks @bkunzi01. I think that's the problem. I've run `bundle update`, which updated Turbolinks from 2.5.3 to 5.0.1. and now 'turbolinks:load' is working on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running bundle update updated Turbolinks from 2.5.3 to 5.0.1. and now 'turbolinks:load' is working on localhost.